# SSIS 2012 package takes long time in pre-execute phase

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have a SSIS package in which the DFT is taking long time to load the data , the data is very less and when we run the query in SSMS it completes in seconds.

When we checked the execution report found out that pre-execute phase is taking long time. For example it took 39 min and then the execution completed within seconds.

2014-10-14 **00:07:06.8913781** -07:00 DFT_LOAD_PRJ_SAR_NON_COMPL_FACT:Information: Execute phase is beginning.

2014-10-13 **23:28:04.6633606** -07:00 DFT_LOAD_PRJ_SAR_NON_COMPL_FACT:Information: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.

2014-10-13 **23:28:04.6545721** -07:00 DFT_LOAD_PRJ_SAR_NON_COMPL_FACT:Information: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.

We have validated that the connection managers for OLE DB sources are all set to DelayValidation ( = True) and checked that ValidateExternalMetadata is set to false

Please advise on the same.

Comment: Why would setting DelayValidation and ValidateExternalMetadata provide an improved execution performance?

Comment: This question does not provide enough information to diagnose the problem. What is happening in your Pre-Execute phase? Do you have data flow? Do these data flows have Lookup Transformation? Do you use a cloud based connection? Is there a dialup connection in the mix?

Comment: It's a data flow task only which is loading the data from a source to destination table . There is no lookup transformation in the DFT.

Comment: are you using a stored procedure with parameters as a source ?

Comment: Nope its a SQL query only.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, packages take ages to validate compared to running them, in BIDS. This did not improve anything: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918644